# Pandas DateOffset, Periods and tslib.period_ordinal

Tags: pandas

I am trying to understand the relationship in Pandas between `DateOffset`, `Periods` and `tslib.period_ordinal`.

When I create a new Period using: `pd.Period("2013-12", freq="Q-DEC")`, 
I see that "Q-DEC" is resolved to a `base` of 2000, this `base` in addition to the components of a `datetime` parsed from the date string are passed to `tslib.period_ordinal` which returns  175.

Where if anywhere does `DateOffset` come in? What is the meaning of the base? Are there any docs on period_ordinal?

I am looking to add some new Frequencies, such as 52–53-week fiscal year (see: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4511) and was wondering where to start.